# wrong params passed to jquery

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing

**update: Ok, I have found a workaround. If I send an int, rather than a string, it's passed right. So it has to do with string passing, lesser than "0008000000", probably?**

**I can just thing of jquery. It's the only code between PHP and the jquery Script. I use jquery V.3.1.1**

I have following Ajax Request:

```
function postday(day,month,year,id){
  alert(id); // => 0000342391
  id = ("0000000000" + id).slice(-10); //add leading zeros
  day = ("00" + day).slice(-2);
  month = ("00" + month).slice(-2);
  $.post("calendarresults.php",{day:day,month:month,year:year,id:id},
  function(data){
    $("#results").html(data);
  });
}
```

html/PHP:

```
var_dump($id); // => 0001234567
echo "<li class='thumbnail'  id='icontopointer' onclick='postday(".$intday.",".$month.",".$year.",".$id.")'>".$intday."</li>";
```

The id param is modified, while passed in some way. I don't understand it.
With some params it works, and others not, example:

```
passing: "0009551064" => "0009551064" 
passing: "0001234567" => "0000342391" 
passing: "0005364421" => "0001435921"
passing: 0004551064 => 1233460
passing: 0005551064 => 1495604
passing: 0006551064 => 1757748
passing: 0007551064 => 2019892
passing: 0008551064 => 8551064
passing: 0009551064 => 9551064
```

What's going on? I don't see a pattern either.

regards

Comment: There must be some logic interfering in the generation of the AJAX, or perhaps the values are simply not what you expect them to be. The code that you've shown will not cause this problem,

Comment: I have deactivated all other scripts and it still modifies the id param. Is there a way I can debug the passing of the params?

Comment: You can see what's sent in the request through the Network tab of the console, in Chrome at least. I'm sure other browsers have equivalents in their dev tools

Comment: It would really help to see an actual working example of this. Could you edit your question to include the HTML output only (not the PHP)

Comment: I have added the HTML output

Comment: The following requests are made, when loading the page:
send https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:16836
ajax https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:13668
r[b] https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4:14655
postday http://localhost/tracker/usersc/time_edit.php:199:3
onclick http://localhost/tracker/usersc/time_edit.php:1:1

Comment: Ok, I have found a workaround. If I send an int, rather than a string, it's passed right. So it has to do with string passing, lesser than "0008000000", probably?